# Nivo Slider transition effects and Workz Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider

I'm trying to alter the transition effects on the Nivo Slider that comes on the home page of the Workz theme (found [here](http://www.wpexplorer.com/workz-wordpress-theme)), but cannot find the javascript. I've looked in the PHP files but unless I'm missing it somwehere, I don't seem to be able see the relevant script. I want to change the effect to 'fade' only and slow the transitions down to about 5-6 seconds. There's no slider menu with the theme. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into functions.php and traced back the shortcode or php code for homepage slider somewhere. I can see the comments on homepage slider in source and the slider js is coming from themes folder which means its not a plugin but actually part of theme. It must be something used in homepage header or actual page content as a short code. I have not got the source code otherwise it is easy to change in this file yourwordpressurl/wp-content/themes/workz/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js?ver=3.5 line 8 and 9 of the file shows speed and duration that you can change in miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find the settings anywhere in theme particularly in functions.php then try to change this javascript file in

yourwordpressurl/wp-content/themes/workz/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js?ver=3.5

line 8 and 9 of the file shows speed and duration that you can change in miliseconds
change 3000 to 5000 or 6000
the line with effect: 'random' change 'random' to 'fade'

```
jQuery(function($){
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider_nivo').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown' <-- set to fade
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 300, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show <-- this is 3 seconds
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
        directionNavHide: false, // Only show on hover
        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel: false, // Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav: true, // Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity: 0.6, // Universal caption opacity
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    }); // END nivo
    });// END window load
  });// END function
```

Change the line with 3000 to 5000 or 6000 to set to 5 or 6 seconds.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Farrukh. I was almost going to give up on the theme, which I otherwise like until you gave me the answer. For extra clarification for anyone else, I had to edit the js file via FTP, using the path given above, and then making the the appropriate changes as also outlined above.